# componentDidMount() не работает при роутинге с динамическим url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Почему в React-контейнере может не работать `componentDidMount()` при повторной попытке вызвать компонент?

Имеется список ссылок вида

```
<Link key={element.name} to={'elements/:element'}} />
```

из ссылки я беру название этого элемента и передаю в props контейнеру ElementDetail (условно так)

```
<ElementDetail name={:element} />
```

`name` из `props` я уже использую внутри метода `componentDidMount()`:

```js
@connect(
    state => ({ element: state.element }),
    dispatch => ({elementActions: bindActionCreators(elementActions, dispatch)})
)
export default class ElementDetail extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('>>> CDM')

        let { getProperties } = this.props.elementActions;
        getProperties(this.props.name)
    }

    render() {
        let { properties, isLoading } = this.props.element;
        let propertyGroups = properties['properties'];

        console.log('>>> RENDER')

        return <div />
```

При первом монтировании компонента код срабатывает как нужно.

Однако, при повторной попытке вызвать компонент c с другими данными через Link, я получаю только обновление адреса в браузере и изменение `props.name`. Работает только код внутри render(), что я вижу по выводу консоли.
Где я допускаю ошибку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без полного кода сложно сказать, но очевидно, что компонент не инициализируется второй раз, а обновляется. Это можно проверить в `componentWillReceiveProps()`. Если второй раз вызывается `componentWillReceiveProps()`, а не `componentDidMount()`, значит нужно работать с `componentWillReceiveProps()`.

Дело в том, что при отправке новых `props` компонент не инициализируется повторно, а лишь принимает новые `props`.

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted
>
> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component receives new props

Comment: Да, вы правы второй раз вызывается componentWillReceiveProps. Если правильно понял, метод componentWillReceiveProps не вызывается для инициализации рендера. Я использую componentDidMount(), чтобы выполнить getProperties(this.props.name), в котором выполняется аякс запрос к серверу. И будет ли правильно выполнять асинхронный код в методе componentWillReceiveProps? Для таких действий, на сколько я знаю, используется componentDidMount().

Comment: Если вам нужно обновить state при получении новых props, то componentDidMount - это самое единственное верное место для этого.

Answer (score 2):

Нашел два решения.

**Первое** - добавил key-аттрибут на компонент, key изменяется (беру из роутинга) и это заставляет реакт перемонтировать компонент

```js
let name = this.props.params.element;
...
<ElementDetail name={name} key={name} />
```

Измение key вызывает каждый раз ComponentDidMount()

```js
@connect(
    state => ({ element: state.element }),
    dispatch => ({elementActions: bindActionCreators(elementActions, dispatch)})
)
export default class ElementDetail extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        let { getProperties } = this.props.elementActions;
        getProperties(this.props.name)
    }
    
    ...
```

**Второе** - использование componentWillReceiveProps() (спасибо [Nick](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/237588/nick) за наводку)

```js
let name = this.props.params.element;
...
<ElementDetail name={name} />
```

И в самом компоненте

```js
@connect(
    state => ({ element: state.element }),
    dispatch => ({elementActions: bindActionCreators(elementActions, dispatch)})
)
export default class ElementDetail extends React.Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.name !== this.props.name) {
            let { getProperties } = this.props.elementActions;
            getProperties(nextProps.name)
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let { getProperties } = this.props.elementActions;
        getProperties(this.props.name)
    }


...
```

но во втором способе больше кода и он дублируется.

Если кто-то даст свои пояснения и замечания, будет отлично

Comment: В данном случае лучше больше кода, чем каждый раз инициализировать компонент. `React DOM compares the element and its children to the previous one, and only applies the DOM updates necessary to bring the DOM to the desired state.`. И чтобы не дублировать код `let { getProperties } = this.props.elementActions; getProperties(this.props.name)` можно вынести в отдельную функцию