# Ререндеринг компонента в Route с динамическим url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь вывести данные с разных url через один компонент. Данные выводятся но при изменении url берутся с изначального запроса. `componentDidMount` (смотри код ниже) срабатывает только при первом рендеринге компонента. Прошу вашей помощи. Нужно чтобы компонент рендерился каждый раз заново с новыми данными при изменении его динамического url.

```
<Route path="/animals/:type/:advertisment" component={AnimalCard} />

componentDidMount() {
    let animal_type = this.props.params.type;
    let advertisment = this.props.params.advertisment;

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8091/list-animals?animal_type=" + animal_type + "&advertisement_type=" + advertisment,
        dataType: "json",
        success: (data) => {
            //здесь в Redux Store отправляются полученные данные
            this.props.getServerData(data);
            console.log("ele" + animal_type, advertisment);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: мы задали этот вопрос почти одновременно) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/631360/componentdidmount-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Продублирую из [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/631360/componentdidmount-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-url) вопроса свой ответ, проблема аналогичная, попробуй адаптировать под свой код

> Нашел два решения.
>
> **Первое** - добавил key-аттрибут на компонент, key изменяется (беру из роутинга) и это заставляет реакт перемонтировать компонент
>
> ```js
> let name = this.props.params.element;
> ...
> <ElementDetail name={name} key={name} />
> ```
>
> Измение key вызывает каждый раз ComponentDidMount()
>
> ```js
> @connect(
>     state => ({ element: state.element }),
>     dispatch => ({elementActions: bindActionCreators(elementActions, dispatch)})
> )
> export default class ElementDetail extends React.Component {
>     componentDidMount() {
>         let { getProperties } = this.props.elementActions;
>         getProperties(this.props.name)
>     }
>
>     ...
> ```
>
> **Второе** - использование componentWillReceiveProps() (спасибо [Nick](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/631360/componentdidmount-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-url) за наводку)
>
> ```js
> let name = this.props.params.element;
> ...
> <ElementDetail name={name} />
> ```
>
> И в самом компоненте
>
> ```js
> @connect(
>     state => ({ element: state.element }),
>     dispatch => ({elementActions: bindActionCreators(elementActions, dispatch)})
> )
> export default class ElementDetail extends React.Component {
>     componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
>         if (nextProps.name !== this.props.name) {
>             let { getProperties } = this.props.elementActions;
>             getProperties(nextProps.name)
>         }
>     }
>
>     componentDidMount() {
>         let { getProperties } = this.props.elementActions;
>         getProperties(this.props.name)
>     }
>
>
> ...
> ```
>
> но во втором способе больше кода и он дублируется.
>
> Если кто-то даст свои пояснения и замечания, будет отлично   [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/631360/componentdidmount-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-url):
>   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/237588/nick

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь. Помог первый вариант.